# Is there any way to convert the string back to previous one?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The Question Description:

You write all your passwords in a diary so that you don't forget them. But clearly, this is too risky, so you came up with a simple plan, you will simply write it by shifting all the alphabets by a certain step. For eg: if you decide your step to be 3, then 'a' will become 'd', and 'k' will become 'n' and so for all alphabets. The last alphabets will simply circle back to 'a'. In this case, 'y' will become 'b' and so on. Now you just have to remember the step size, can then you can check the password anytime you want.

---

Input:

A list of two elements.

The first element will be a string consisting of only alphabets that are taken from the diary and the second element will be the step size.

Output:

A string denoting the password

---

```
Sample input: ['ytLvei', 4]

Sample output: upHrae
```

Explanation:

The password was 'upHrae'. Upon changing it by step of 4,

u became y,

p became t,

H became L,

r became v,

a became e,

e became i,

and thus what was written in the diary was ytKveh

---

```
Sample input: ['banana', 7]

Sample output: utgtgt
```

To get the above output I have written the code is given below.

```
import at
n = ast.literal_eval(input())
n1 = n[0]
step = n[1]
def enc_dec(string,step):
    result = ''
    for i in string:
        temp = ''
        if i=='':
            result = result+i
        elif i.isupper():
            temp = chr((ord(i) - step - 65) % 26 + 65)
        else:
            temp = chr((ord(i) - step - 97) % 26 + 97)
        result = result + temp
    return result
print(enc_dec(n1,step))
```

My sample test cases i.e.

```
Sample input1: ['banana', 7]

Sample output2: utgtgt

Sample input2: ['ytLvei', 4]

Sample output2: upHrae
```

Both the above sample inputs are passing but when I try to convert the **'upHare'** to **'ytLvei'** I am getting another output i.e. **'qlCnwz'**.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are changing it *up* by step of 4. You need to change it down by 4. Your code doesn't work either-- you can't add and subtract ints by strs in python!
Here is a new code that should work:

```py
letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
def convert_str(string, step):
    converted = ""
    for char in string:
        if char != "Z":
            converted += letters[letters.index(char) + step]
        else:
            converted += letters[step-1]
    return converted

in_str = input("string: ")
print(convert_str(in_str, 4))
```

This will make `upHare` to `ytLevi`.
To convert down, use negative numbers:

```py
print(convert_str(in_str, -4))
```

Comment: I am trying to add the condition                                                                                  
            temp = chr((ord(i) + step - 65) % 26 + 65)
        else:
            temp = chr((ord(i) + step - 97) % 26 + 97)                                                          by which string will reverse back to previous. But I am not getting how to add this condition in the code so that this above condition will work. Can you please help me.

Comment: I think you should find a different way to increase the letter by 4.

Comment: could you please suggest one I am trying to solve this from the past 3 days but couldn't get any solution till now.

Comment: @nidhibhatnagar -- I've updated my post. Sorry for the late reply, I was busy.

Comment: No problem but the thing is I cannot add negative signs in input to get the desired output. The input is already given to me and I need to code as per the given input only this is the reason which took me this long to write the code for this problem and still not getting the solution.

Comment: @nidhibhatnagar -- Ah, I see. If that is so, then how would you know whether to encode it or decode it?

Comment: Thanks, @Xilpex I confirmed with my mentor and he told me that I need to decrypt the message only. To create Encryption and Decryption we have to create 2 functions. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The cipher as described rotates the alphabet in one direction to encode, and another to decode; they aren't interchangeable operations.  If you aren't allowed to specify a negative step when testing your input, then define different functions for encoding/decoding:

```
def encode(message: str, step: int) -> str:
    return enc_dec(message, step)

def decode(message: str, step: int) -> str:
    return enc_dec(message, -step)
```

Now you can do:

```
>>> print(decode('upHrae', 4))
ytLvei
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work even when the cases are different lower or higher

```
import ast
n = ast.literal_eval(input())
string = n[0]
step = n[1]
letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
l1='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
l2='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
converted = ""
def convert_str(string, step):
    converted = ""
    for char in string:
        if char.islower():

            converted += l1[l1.index(char) + step]
        elif char.isupper():
            converted += l2[l2.index(char) + step]
        elif char != "Z":
            converted += letters[letters.index(char) + step]
            print(converted)
        else:
            converted += letters[step-1]
    return converted
print(convert_str(string, -step))
```